# SLF4J version mismatch with GATE stanford parser

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, gate

I am trying to use stanford parser in GATE and this is the error I am getting.
The requested version 1.5.6 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6, 1.7]

Now, I have downloaded a file a slf4j-api-1.5.6 and have put it in same location as I had my slf4j-api-1.7 file. (ivy2\cache\org.slf4j\slf4j-api\jars) This path is also set as a classpath.

I also deleted slf-4j-1.7 but it keeps reoccurring itself every time I start GATE.

How should I resolve this issue? Any suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try my solution for your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/38192247/1857897

Comment: ... I think the issue is still the same, what other plugins are you having loaded in GATE?

Comment: @dedek I tried the same thing with GATE 8.1 . Somehow it is working on 8.1 version.

Comment: Sure, **GATE 8.1** version of Stanford_CoreNLP plugin **doesn't use slf4j** at all.